# Label of custom UITableViewHeaderFooterView cut off

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView with custom section footers. Each footer has a label that is supposed to display multiple lines of text. In some labels, my text gets truncated and I would like to know how to avoid that. Here's an example:

[image]

As you can see, two of the three labels are cut off. I would like the labels to expand with the text (just like the label in the middle).

Here's a project demonstrating the problem [github](https://github.com/nambatee/CustomTableFooterLabelSizing)

My custom footer class:

```
class CustomFooter: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

public static var nib: UINib {
    return UINib(nibName: "CustomFooter", bundle: nil)
}

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

public func heightWithExpectedWidth(_ width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = width;
    return systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
}
```

}

and relevant methods from my view controller class:

```
private let cellReuseIdentifier = "CellReuseIdentifier"
private let footerReuseIdentifier = "FooterReuseIdentifier"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)
    tableView.register(CustomFooter.nib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: footerReuseIdentifier)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    guard let footer = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: footerReuseIdentifier) as? CustomFooter else {
        return nil
    }
    footer.label.text = sections[section].footerText
    return footer
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    guard let footer = self.tableView(tableView, viewForFooterInSection: section) as? CustomFooter else {
        return 0
    }
    return footer.heightWithExpectedWidth(tableView.bounds.width)
}
```

I have tried playing with constraints and `heightFor` methods but without any luck. I don't understand the root of the problem and any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

project demonstrating the problem [github](https://github.com/nambatee/CustomTableFooterLabelSizing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Remove `public func heightWithExpectedWidth(_ width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat` from your `CustomFooter.swift`
2. Add below code to `viewDidLoad` method of your view controller

   tableView.sectionFooterHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
   tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 44
3. Update your `heightForFooterInSection` method like below:

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
   guard let _ = self.tableView(tableView, viewForFooterInSection: section) as? CustomFooter else {
   return 0
   }
   return UITableView.automaticDimension
   }

Now, it should work.

**Update**

To support orientation changes, add the code below:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
  super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
  tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: thank you so much!!! it works everywhere, except for when I rotate iPhone X to landscape  do you have any idea how to fix that?